# What function should I use to listen for when someone changes tab in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write a function that when a user clicks away from the current tab (or clicks on another tab) then a script runs. I was thinking the onEdit() function, but that only works when cells are changed. What function should I use?

Comment: There's not currently an [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that can detect if the user changed tabs... the `onChange` will be fired only if the user change something in the spreadsheet, for example rename a tab. There can be some workarounds, but can you explain in a little more detail what you want to achieve, for example you want to change the content of the sidebar depending on the active tab?

Comment: I've got a sheet where a column always needs to be sorted ascending (the rest of the sheet dependencies work off that basis), but it's also a sheet which people tend to change the sort to get different views, so I wanted to do something like: function onEdit(){    range.sort(1);
}

Comment: One workaround is to include a custom menu (or a script-linked button) that executes a "Reset" by sorting that sheet. You could also make a time-driven trigger that executes the sort every few minutes, see the Installable Triggers  reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually

Comment: Since you don't have an active sidebar to detect the user's behavior, I can't think on another way to achieve that (in addition to those already mentioned by Tiffany). Considering that the people frequently change the order of that column, It is not possible to eliminate the dependence on the order of that column?

Comment: You could just give each user their own image of the data that they can play with. You could make a new Sheet, then onOpen, copy or update that sheet from the master (protected, of course). Without some code to work with, it's hard to come up with examples. How are you handling the 'other sheet dependencies' when someone is viewing the data in the critical sheet? Do the other sheets break when a user sorts by a different column, say?